# python how to transfer between a list of integers and string of bits?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I have a list of integers, each integer in range [0,255]. I want to transfer this into a string of bits. Each integer use  8 bits to represent. After I handle string of bits, I want to transfer it into a list of integers, every 8-bit to a integer. How to do it?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your attempt and explain your difficulties please.

Comment: You might start by looking into the [`b` "presentation type"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for use in `"<format>" % <int>` or `"<format>".format(<int>)` as well as the [second form of the `int` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) that accepts a `base` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need external library. Use python's built-in function.

integer to binary:

```
i = 100
print "{0:08b}".format(i)
```

binary to integer:

```
b = "01100100"
print int(b, 2)
```

If you need to build a large bit array, then using `bitarray` module is good, as what you did in your answer:

```
bits = bitarray()
for i in pixels: bits.extend("{0:08b}".format(i))
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't describy my question clearly. After transforming to bits, I will manipulate them. If using string to represent, it will consume all my memory.

Comment: Because python int isn't all 4bytes，I can't use bit offset to handle bits likes what i do using C

Comment: I see, then you can make use of `bitarray` as what you've done in your answer. I also edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. This is my answer:

```
from PIL import Image
from bitarray import bitarray
from bitstring import BitArray


class Compress:
    def readFile(self, filename):
        self.img = Image.open(filename)
        self.pixels = list(self.img.getdata())  # a list of int--[0,255]

    def __toBitArray__(self):
        self.bits = bitarray()
        for i in self.pixels:
            self.bits.extend(BitArray(uint=i, length=8).bin)
        print(self.bits.length())

    def saveFile(self, filename):
        p = []
        for i in range(self.bits.length()//8):
            b = self.bits[i*8:i*8+8].to01()
        p.append(BitArray(bin=b).uint)
        self.img.putdata(p)
        self.img.save(filename)
        self.img.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Compress()
    c.readFile('num.bmp')
    c.__toBitArray__()
    c.saveFile('test.bmp')
```